# BreezeJs query with nested objects

Tags: angular, breeze

I would like execute the following query:

```
let query = EntityQuery.from("ResearchApplication")
                       .where("Deleted", FilterQueryOp.Equals, false)
                       .where("ResearchApplicationFiles.FileInformation", FilterQueryOp.Any, "Deleted", FilterQueryOp.Equals, false)
                       .expand("ResearchApplicationFiles")
                       .expand("ResearchApplicationFiles.FileInformation")
```

ResearchApplicationFiles.FileInformation constains a list of FileInformation and I would like to filter that list where "Deleted" is false.

I keep getting this exception:

The parent value for a property access of a property 'FileInformation' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
EntityQuery.from("ResearchApplication")
    .where("Deleted", FilterQueryOp.Equals, false)
    .where("ResearchApplicationFiles", FilterQueryOp.Any, "FileInformation.Deleted", FilterQueryOp.Equals, false)
    .expand("ResearchApplicationFiles")
    .expand("ResearchApplicationFiles.FileInformation")
```

Note the change in the `Any` clause.

See more examples on the [Breeze query examples page](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/query-examples.html#WhereAnyAll)